# How do I show the return code of the previous command in the Windows command line prompt?

Tags: windows, command-line

I recall being able to do this and the documentation I've found indicates that `$r` should show the return code (aka. "exit code") of the previous command. When I try this, the prompt terminates at the location of `$r` as follows:

```
prompt $+$p$crc=$r$f$g
```

results in the following

```
C:\Temp(rc=
```

If I remove `$r` as follows, I get the full prompt:

```
prompt $+$p$crc=$f$g

C:\Temp(rc=)>
```

Has this feature been dropped from Windows, do I need to "turn it on", or is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Has this feature been dropped from Windows?

`$R` has never been a special code for the prompt text in a Windows `cmd` shell.

To display the error code use the following command:

```
echo %errorlevel%
```

You can set the prompt to include the error level, but you get the value of `errorlevel` at the time the prompt is set so it never changes.

```
prompt %errorlevel%
```

Note:

`$R` does return the error level in an OS/2 command prompt:

> $R     Error level (OS/2)

Source [Enhancing your PROMPT with ANSI sequences](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/prompt.php)

---

#### help prompt

```
Prompt can be made up of normal characters and the following special codes:

  $A   & (Ampersand)
  $B   | (pipe)
  $C   ( (Left parenthesis)
  $D   Current date
  $E   Escape code (ASCII code 27)
  $F   ) (Right parenthesis)
  $G   > (greater-than sign)
  $H   Backspace (erases previous character)
  $L   < (less-than sign)
  $N   Current drive
  $P   Current drive and path
  $Q   = (equal sign)
  $S     (space)
  $T   Current time
  $V   Windows version number
  $_   Carriage return and linefeed
  $$   $ (dollar sign)

If Command Extensions are enabled the PROMPT command supports
the following additional formatting characters:

  $+   zero or more plus sign (+) characters depending upon the
       depth of the PUSHD directory stack, one character for each
       level pushed.

  $M   Displays the remote name associated with the current drive
       letter or the empty string if current drive is not a network
       drive.
```

Comment: When you put `%errorlevel%` in the prompt you get the value of `errorlevel` at the time the prompt is set so it never changes.

Comment: Must be something from my OS/2 days that I remember using. Sigh - a nice fearure.